# decrypt with XOR JAVA working on first line only

Tags: java, encryption, xor

I am working on a file/directory processing assignment and I encrypted the file (to hex then XOR). The file I need to decrypt is in hexadecimal so I need to decrypt then un hex. However only the first line of my file gets decrypted correctly.(key is shorter than file so it is repeated hence the keyItr)
This is the encrypt code:

```
String encrypHexa="";
Scanner x = new Scanner(f);
while(x.hasNext()){
String a= x.nextLine();
int keyItr=0;
for (int i=0; i<a.length();i++){
//XOR
int temp = a.charAt(i) ^ key.charAt(keyItr);             
encrypHexa += String.format("%02x",(byte)temp);                     
keyItr++;      
if(keyItr==key.length()){ 
                keyItr=0;                                       }                                            }
        } System.out.println("Encrypted is: " +encrypHexa);
```

This is the Decrypt code:

```
String hexiToDeci="";

Scanner x = new Scanner(f);

while(x.hasNext()){

String a= x.nextLine();

for (int i=0;i<a.length()-1;i+=2){

String output=a.substring(i,i+2);

int decimal = Integer.parseInt(output,16);

hexiToDeci += (char)decimal;

}
                                                    //Decrypt with XOR
int keyItr=0;
for (int i=0; i<hexiToDeci.length();i++){
//XOR
int temp = hexiToDeci.charAt(i) ^ key.charAt(keyItr);
decrypText +=(char)temp;                                                         keyItr++;
                                                        if(keyItr==key.length()){                                                             keyItr=0;                                                    }                                                    }
}
System.out.println("Encrypted is: " +decrypText);
```

input:

```
new new new new
old old old old
```

encrypted:
3f1212521a1c024901152c115c56533e1b01521b151149001c3f115d5f40
output:

```
new new new new?4d,H1wyMe$*)e
```

tested with key:Qwertyuiop[123$4$567]
 What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `int keyItr = 0` inside the `while` loop in your encryption function, so it gets reset at the end of every line in the source text. In the decryption function, however, since the encrypted text is just a single line without break, the while loop never repeats and `keyItr` is only reset after hitting the limit.

So move the `keyItr` initialization before the while loop in your encryption function and it'll not give you junk anymore. But the decrypted text will still not be an accurate reproduction of the source text, because newlines in the source text are swallowed by the encryption's `Scanner`. To avoid this, either:

a) If your source files are small, use the EOF character as the encryption Scanner's delimiter.

[OR]

b) Manually append the newline in your encryption function, before you encrypt like so:

```
...
String a = x.nextLine();
// Add this if
if (x.hasNext()) {
    a += System.lineSeparator();
}
for (int i=0; i<a.length();i++){
...
```

[Here is a demo](https://ideone.com/gZZoZ5)

P.S: Please `close()` your `Scanner`s!

Comment: Wow! Thanks for not only answering the question but also solving my next problem! Great explanation and code!

Comment: I have another problem now, it is only going through some of the input file and abruptly stops at the same spot with no errors or anything and perfect output just not the whole output. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @Fatima Sorry, that's not enough info. Perhaps you could post a new question with just that problem clearly stated and relevant code?